# XML to Table <for-each>

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to turn the following into a table, but I am having a hard time understanding how it parses through all of the child nodes. Will it go through each element until the last one or do I need to have a for-each for each parent node? Also, if there are multiple occurrences of "capris" allowed, do I need to have cells for each possible occurrence (say if there are 3 max but I only have 2, then I would still need 3 cells displayed).

**XML:**

```
<Persons xmlns = "">
<Person>
   <Shirts>One</Shirts>
   <Pants>
      <Jeans>
          <Shorts>One</Shorts>
          <Capris>One</Capris>
          <Capris>Two</Capris>
      </Jeans>
      <Dress>One</Dress>
   </Pants>
</Person>
<Person>
   <Shirts>One</Shirts>
   <Pants>
      <Jeans>
          <Shorts>One</Shorts>
          <Capris>One</Capris>
          <Capris>Two</Capris>
          <Capris>Three</Capris>
      </Jeans>
      <Dress>One</Dress>
   </Pants>
</Person>
</Persons>
```

**XSL:**

```
<table border="1">
   <tr bgcolor="yellow"> 
   <td><b>Shirts</b></td> 
   <td><b>Shorts</b></td> 
   <td><b>Capris</b></td>
   <td><b>Capris</b></td>
   <td><b>Capris</b></td>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="Persons">
  <xsl:sort select="Persons/Persib" />
    <tr style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: verdana">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Shirts"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Shorts"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Capris"/></td>    
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had your `xsl:for-each` matching rule wrong.
Use the following template: it matches the root `<Persons>` element, creates the `<html>` and `<body>` elements and the `<table>`.

Finally, it iterates over the `<Person>` elements with an `xsl:for-each`. This works, because the context node is right (`Person` is a child of `Persons`).

The `Capris` situation is resolved by iterating over all `Capris` elements and creating a `<td>` for each present element. You can see this by looking at the borders of the elements.

One thing left to be corrected is the `xsl:sort` element. It tries to sort by the value of a `<Persib>` element which is not present in the example. I guess that you can fix this on your own.

```
<xsl:template match="/Persons">   
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="yellow"> 
                    <td><b>Shirts</b></td>
                    <td><b>Shorts</b></td>
                    <td><b>Capris</b></td>
                    <td><b>Capris</b></td>
                    <td><b>Capris</b></td>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="Person">
                    <xsl:sort select="Persib" />
                    <tr style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: verdana">
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Shirts"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Pants/Jeans/Shorts"/>
                        </td>

                        <xsl:for-each select="Pants/Jeans/Capris">
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                            </td>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

The output should be as desired.

Comment: May be spaning issue if some Capris inside Jeans not coming or some addition will come.